# about the prototype and parameter in javascript-from book [javascript-spessore]

Tags: javascript

I have a problem when reading javascript-spessore; 
The problem comes from the relation between parameter and prototype, 
the following is the code snippet, and I put it in https://jsfiddle.net/abramhum/wf0vom9x/4/

```
function Class() {
  return {
    create: function() {
      var instance = Object.create(this.prototype);
      Object.defineProperty(instance, 'constructor', {
        value: this
      });
      if (instance.initialize) {
        instance.initialize.apply(instance, arguments);
      }
      return instance;
    },
    defineMethod: function(name, body) {
      this.prototype[name] = body;
      return this;
    },
    prototype: {}
  };
}

var QuadTree = Class();

QuadTree.defineMethod(
  'initialize',
  function(nw, ne, se, sw) {
    this.nw = nw;
    this.ne = ne;
    this.se = se;
    this.sw = sw;
  }
).defineMethod(
  'population',
  function() {
    return this.nw.population() + this.ne.population() +
      this.se.population() + this.sw.population();
  }
);

var BasicObjectClass = {
  prototype: {}
}

function Class(superclass) {
  return {
    create: function() {
      var instance = Object.create(this.prototype);
      Object.defineProperty(instance, 'constructor', {
        value: this
      });
      if (instance.initialize) {
        instance.initialize.apply(instance, arguments);
      }
      return instance;
    },
    defineMethod: function(name, body) {
      this.prototype[name] = body;
      return this;
    },
    prototype: Object.create(superclass.prototype)
  };
}

var QuadTree = Class(BasicObjectClass);
```

when I run, the error message shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined", there doesn't exist prototype of superclass.
This seems like an error, but there is no any explanation about that in 
this book. Is any one know the answer, and why it not correct, and how to 
correct it? Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you want class like syntax, use ES6,  also what is this supposed to do ?

Comment: Your defining both `Class` and `QuadTree` twice in your code. Don't do that. (Hint: the second `Class` *declaration* is hoisted, and used for the first call as well). If you execute the *two* snippets from the book after each other, it'll work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are falling into trouble because of function hoisting. You have define two different functions with:

```
function Class()
```

When you do this javascript 'hoists' these to the top, which means that the second one is always called. So the first time you call…

```
var QuadTree = Class();
```

…you are actually calling the second function. And since you aren't passing a parameter, the parameter `superclass` is undefined. This is why it's a bad idea to re-use function names.

Renaming the first function to something like `Class1()` and changing the call to `var QuadTree = Class1()` makes the error go away.

Comment: +1 for not saying that it was a bad idea to use function declarations          
                                                                                                                      
                     :-)